# RBS for SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, rbs

I was able to setup RBS for one content DB. It has been implemented for a year.The minimum size is 50MB.  Any documents less than 50MB will go to SQL table, and 50MB or more go to RBS folder.

Recently, I need to setup additional content DB for RBS.  It worked in the development environment.

But when I implemented RBS for additional DB in production, it migrated all the documents to RBS folder.

When I added documents less than 50MB, it still go to the RBS folder. I setup the minimum file size is 50MB.

Please let me know why it not working for the additional content DB in Prod?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.  You just make sure the minimum size for all the servers.  If the minimum size was not set, make sure to set it again, and run the update command.